# STL Data Structure for O(log n) or less delete and access time

Tags: c++, stl

***Is there a STL DS for O(log n) or less delete and access time  ?***
Here is my problem-- say i have a set of number 1 3 5 6 7 . i want to insert only at the last of my array. however i want to erase at any place. suppose i want to delete 3rd element. after that my array would become 1 3 6 7. and i want to access at any place so if i want i can access 3rd element now which is 6. for either operation highest complexity  i can have is O(log n).

Comment: Please, do not post this kind of elementary question at Stack Overflow. You can find an answer to this easily in Wikipedia.

Comment: There are a handful of them all well documented on cppreference.com including time complexity. Would it have been so hard to go there and read that first?

Comment: **−1** No research and needless use of mystifying acronyms.

Comment: _@Saad_ Not much improvement after edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::map`, and `std::multimap`, which has O(log n) insertion, erasure, and searching time complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain how to access or delete i_th element on std::map

Comment: @SaadMahmud You should start here... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/

Comment: These containers have elements in a strict order. "i_th element on std::map" means "Element with i_th least key on std::map". Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Get the start iterator by calling member function `begin`, and advance it by `i-1` by `std::advance`. And dereference it.

Comment: @DannyuNDos http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem RUN!!

Comment: @DannyuNDos Thanks for your answer. This part helped "begin, and advance it by i-1 by std::advance" . Sorry for my naive question.